# SSH Tunnel can't connect - connection times out, even though regular login works

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, tunneling, socks

I am trying to set up an SSH tunnel with a SOCKS proxy in Firefox, so I can surf the internet securely from public wifi. Both client and server are running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

After setting up port forwarding on my router (port 8888 forwards to port 22 on my server at home, at least for this example), I am able to log in via ssh normally using the command:

```
ssh -p 8888 user@hostname
```

However, when I follow the "standard" directions for setting up the tunnel, I cannot connect. The directions tell me to use this command:

```
ssh -D 8888 user@hostname
```

But all I get is a connection timeout:

```
ssh: connect to host hostname port 22: Connection timed out
```

I haven't found any other helpful posts on here (or elsewhere). Any suggestions or ideas? I already added the following line to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server and restarted sshd:

```
AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

Same result. Suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have mixed up what exactly happens here. `ssh -p` will tell the ssh client on which port the server is listening, and `-D` will tell it on which port it should listen *locally* as SOCKS proxy.

You should use it like this:

```
ssh -p 8888 -D 5115 user@host
```

Test it with `curl` like this:

```
curl --proxy socks5h://localhost:5115 http://private.example/contacts.html
```

Source: http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/ssh-socks-and-curl/